# Assetic on Symfony won't work in production Symfony

Tags: symfony

I uploaded my SF Application from my local (machine) to production (Cpanel server) 
everything looks fine on production except the css, js, etc. (All files inside the `web` directory.

I open the `var/logs/prod.log` just to check whats happening and I find out these errors.

> request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /stylesheets/base.css" (from "http://example.com/admin/login")" etc.........

Now, what I did is to open the `base.html.twig` and made changes on the path of css/js files.

**From**

`<link href="{{ asset('stylesheets/base.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

**To** the full directory.

`<link href="{{ asset('/home2/swipecom/public_html/web/stylesheets/base.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet" />`

By the way, here's the directory of the application in the server.

home/swipecom

- cache
- contactless (Where SF directories live)
  **- public_html (/web the only SF directory)**
- var
- ssl
- tmp
- public_ftp
- logs

Comment: Can you show your styles and js directories?

Comment: Can you give us an extract of  ```php bin/console debug:parameters``` you have in production ? (masking sensitive data, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using this code

`<link href="{{ asset('web/stylesheets/base.css')  }}" rel="stylesheet" />`